# How can I get the real path in WatchService

Tags: java, java-io

In java, when I add or change or delete any file, I hope the program execute the same action in another directory.It means, if I add a file "test.txt" in E://aaa, the program should copy "test.txt" from E://aaa to D://bbb。

I use `java.nio.file.WatchService` to implement it, but I can not get files' real path in program, Here is my code:

```
public void watchPath(Path watchPath, Path targetPath) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    try (WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
        watchPath.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY,
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);
        while (true) {
            final WatchKey key = watchService.take();
            for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : key.pollEvents()) {
                final Kind<?> kind = watchEvent.kind();
                if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW) {
                    continue;
                }
                final WatchEvent<Path> watchEventPath = (WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent;
                Path systemFileDir = (Path) key.watchable(); // TODO Here can not get the real path
                //System.out.println(systemFileDir.toString()); // E:/aaa
                //System.out.println(systemFileDir.toAbsolutePath()); // E:/aaa
                //System.out.println(systemFileDir.toRealPath()); // E:/aaa
                final Path path = watchEventPath.context();
                String fileAbsPath = systemFileDir + File.separator + path;
                Path original = Paths.get(fileAbsPath);
                String targetAbsPath = fileAbsPath.replace(watchPath.toString(), targetPath.toString());
                Path target = Paths.get(targetAbsPath);
                File file = new File(targetAbsPath);
                if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE || kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                    if (file.isDirectory() && !file.exists()) { // 如果是目录
                        file.mkdirs();
                    } else {
                        Files.copy(original, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    }
                }
                if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE) {
                    Files.delete(target);
                }
            }
            boolean valid = key.reset();
            if (!valid) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now the question is, when I add a file or directory in E://aaa/x, the program can not get the real path. For example, I added the file E://aaa/x/test.txt, I hope I can get this absolute path then copy it to destination, but I just get the RootPath E://aaa。

How Can I solve it ? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

The reason you have the problem is because you only ever register the parent folder. If you want to get an exact path for edits made in a sub folder then you need to register your watcher in those sub folders as well. One way to do this is to [walk through the entire file tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) right at the start and register everything.

Here is a perfect example:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java

Now you just need to modify that code snippet to suite your needs by adjusting the `processEvents()` method to check the event type then use the `child` variable to do the same action in your other folder.

Here is a crude example of an edit you could make to processEvents to go about adding folders in your mirrored directory:

```
    Path child = dir.resolve(name);
    if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE && (check if directory here))
    {
        String destinationToMirror = "D" + child.toString().substring(1);
        File file = new File(destinationToMirror);
        file.mkdir();
    }
```

Else read up on walking the file tree so you can just add the necessary bits to your own code:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

---

**Original Answer:**

<s>Try something like this:</s>

```
Path original = systemFileDir.resolve(watchEventPath.context());
```

Instead of:

```
final Path path = watchEventPath.context();
String fileAbsPath = systemFileDir + File.separator + path;
Path original = Paths.get(fileAbsPath);
```

Note the main difference being how the path is resolved using `dir.resolve`

Credit: [java.nio.file.WatchEvent gives me only relative path. How can I get the absolute path of the modified file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801662/java-nio-file-watchevent-gives-me-only-relative-path-how-can-i-get-the-absolute)

Comment: If I add a folder in E:\\aaa\x, I want to get the path "E:\\aaa\x\y", but `systemFileDir.resolve(watchEventPath.context())` just return "E:\\aaa\x", and I do not know how to get my new folder name "y"。

Comment: @JasonGan See my edits. But in essence: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java